# shell fails when command to the right of || does not exist

Tags: bash, sh

I had an issue with `tar` happening in circumstances involving timestamps on a mounted windows docker volume (long story short), and decided to try `pax`. It worked, but I wanted the script to work as before on old machines until I've installed `pax` everywhere. My command looked like this:

```
tar -czf foo.tar.gz foo || echo "didnt work, trying pax" && echo foo | pax -wz > foo.tar.gz
```

The intent is that `pax` is only run when `tar` fails. But running it on machines without `pax` I get the unexpected error that `pax` does not exist. Unexpected because I thought `||` discards whatever is to the right if preceding command return success. Narrowing it down to a proper test case I've got this, tested with `bash` and `dash`:

```
# as expected, fails trying to run missing command
echo hello && false || echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa
# hello
# trying different command
# bash: dsadsa: command not found

# UNEXPECTED, command is never run but nevertheless fails because it's missing
echo hello && true || echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa
# hello
# bash: dsadsa: command not found

# as expected, does not try run missing command, current solution/workaround
echo hello && true || (echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa)
# hello
```

Why is this happening? And how come sub-shelling works as workaround?

Comment: `a && b || c` is not equivalent to `if a; then b; else c; fi`. `c` will run if `a` *or* `b` fails.

Comment: General rule: don't mix `&&` and `||` in the same chain (they also have equal precedence, unlike Boolean `&` and `|` in other languages). Use an `if` statement if that is what you mean.

Comment: @chepner My understanding is they should be read left-to-right because of equal precedence. `if-then-else` is a good idea, thanks

Comment: @chepner Got it, it should be read as `(a && b) || c`, and not `a && (b || c)`. It all makes sense now.

Comment: BTW, use `a && { b || c; }`, not `a && (b || c)`, if your only purpose is grouping; that way we avoid subshell overhead when you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> || discards whatever is to the right

I think your understanding is wrong, it executes the right side if the left succeeded. The rest still runs depending on the return status.

The shell having this:

```
echo hello && false || echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa
```

groups commands with left-associativity and both `&&` and `||` have the same precedence. So it looks like so:

```
((echo hello && false) || echo 'trying different command') && dsadsa
```

Now the important part comes from [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

> Exit Status
>
> The exit status of an OR list shall be the exit status of the last command that is executed in the list.

The exit status of `a || b` is the exit status of the *last command executed*. So it is the exit status of `a` if it returns with a zero exit status. It is the exit status of `b` if `a` returned with nonzero exit status.

So:

```
echo hello && true || echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa
```

1. `echo hello` succeeds. (Note: success is zero exit status.)
2. So `&& true` is executed.
3. `echo hello && true` succeeds.
4. So `|| echo 'trying different command'` is not executed, because the exit status of `echo hello && true` is zero.
5. So the exit status of `echo hello && true || echo 'trying different command'` is zero, because the exit status of `echo hello && true` is zero.
6. So `&& dsadsa` is executed.

You're "workaround" is the proper solution around it. To "save" some of the resources, you could use `{` braces, because you don't need to run a subshell.

```
echo hello && true || { echo 'trying different command' && dsadsa; }
```

However I wouldn't care about exit status of `echo`s:

```
{ echo hello; true; } || { echo 'trying different command'; dsadsa; }
```

And I would use `if`s anyway:

```
if ! tar -czf foo.tar.gz foo; then
    echo "didnt work, trying pax"
    if ! echo foo | pax -wz > foo.tar.gz; then
       echo "RUN! pax failed too"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Keyword is "left-associativity". I thought it was right-associative. Or I confused left with right... Doesn't matter, I get it now :-)